# Different behavior for Batchnorm with is_training 'true' and 'false' - Accuracy is different for frozen models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to infer mobilenetV2 model.

I have trained the model using tensorflow/models/slim.
The model is giving proper accuracy with `is_training=true`.
But when I do, `is_training=false` and save the model, then inference is giving very less accuracy.

I could see the below difference in the graph in these two cases. 
With `is_training=true`, then `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` become `Const` and `Const_1` respectively. This is the only difference I could see.
And during inference, the output of `FusedBatchNorm` node is different in these two cases.

Please, someone, help me to understand why is it happening and how to resolve this issue?

[image: Comparison of the two graphs]

Comment: Did you measure the accuracy of the same data for `is_training = True` and `is_training = False`. If you are using different data then it might be the case of overfitting.

Comment: I am using the same data for test with is_training = True and is_training = False. I will list the steps what am doing.  1. measured the training accuracy (is_training=true). Saved the checkpoints with is_training=true. 2. Restored the  saved checkpoint (is_training=true) and evaluated. Accuracy is same as the training accuracy. 3. Restored the checkpoint and changed the is_training to false and saved the checkpoint. 4. Created a frozen graph with the checkpoint (is_training=false) 5. Measured accuracy of the model. Accuracy reduced from 65% to 16%.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue.

With TF Document Suggestions as given below :

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)
```

I am getting better Accuracy at TEST with **is_training : False**